# Flutter when Button pressed then start Timer

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently when I hit onPress then I toggle if it scan's for a Device or not, but i'd like to have the Function that when i hit onPressed then it scan's for only the Time i set.

**The Scan Widget**

```
void onScanButtonPressed() {
    if (model.isScanning) {
      model.stopScan();
    } else {
      model.startScan();
    }
  }
```

**The onPressed function**

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: onScanButtonPressed,
                child: Text(model.scanButtonText),
              ),
```

**The Timer function**

```
Duration timer = new Duration(seconds: 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of different ways.

Here is one way, using [Hooks Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Scan with Time',
        home: Scaffold(body: MyWidget()),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

final modelProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<MyModelNotifier, bool>((ref) => MyModelNotifier());

class MyModelNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  MyModelNotifier([state]) : super(state ?? false);

  Timer? _timer;

  void stopScan() => state = false;

  void startScan() {
    state = true;
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () => stopScan());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final scanning = ref.watch(modelProvider);
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => scanning
            ? ref.read(modelProvider.notifier).stopScan()
            : ref.read(modelProvider.notifier).startScan(),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: scanning ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
        ),
        child: Text(scanning ? 'STOP' : 'START'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working bro. kindly update it

Comment: Verily, @RahulKushwaha, the solution from February 2021, two years past, was apt. As Flutter and Riverpod have grown, the old wisdom may falter. Embrace today's knowledge and face new challenges in this evolving realm!

Comment: I resolved the problem I was facing . thanks for update.